# Impossible to fix references after cloning repository from Github C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, xamarin

I forked and cloned a repository from github and each of the 7 projects have references missing. I restored packages for the solution and ran the `Update-Packages -reinstall` command in package manager console and still had 14 warnings about packages.

> Package 'Validation 2.2.8' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Aswell as warnings not displaying but triangles displaying for clsa.analyzers.dll, I'm really confused as to what I have done wrong, can someone give me their step by step for restoring references after cloning a repository?

Comment: What is the target version of the Project? Also what is it targeting, .NET Framework, .NET Core or .NET Standard? It seems like the Project is .NET Framework 4.6.1 but the Package referenced and used only targets .NET Standard 2.0

Comment: 4.6.1 and class libraries using .net standard 2.0

Comment: In which packages is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried just restoring the packages instead of updating them?  Possibly the latest versions of the nuget packages do not supoort .Net standard 2.0 although that seems unlikely.

Comment: PCLCrpyto and csla.analyzer. I seem to have issues all the time with nuget packages

Comment: Yes I did do a restore first, I have tried unistalling and removing all references then reinstalling, doesn't work. Its a straight clone without any changes

Comment: Could I be that I have two hard disks, visual studio is on one and i create all my projects on the other

Answer (score 1):

It loooks like that version v2.2.8  of the Validation package does not support .Net Standard 2.0.  Looks like support was only added at v2.4.15.  You could try updating to the latest version v2.4.18?

Presumably the original developer would have had the same issue.

Comment: I have just grabbed the latest version as of yesterday, surely the latest version would work?

Comment: Do you mean the latest version of the repo or the nuget package?  The orginal developer(s) of the repo may not have updated nuget references to the latest recently